# Publishing to NPM and CDN

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first time writing a very basic JavaScript library and now I intend to publish it. I wrote it as a function and users can simply import the JavaScript file over a CDN. I intend to publish this to NPM too, so users can use it with JS bundlers too.

I created another file to match the Node.js format, basically, I added `module.exports =`  before my function and that's all working. So, now I have ended up with two files with basically the same code, one for CDN and one for NPM. Is there any way to unify this, basically merge it all in the same file?

I would really like to know how this is usually done. When a function is written to be imported as a CDN, how does it get converted to a Node Module? Is creating a separate file the only way, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is easily answered with a quick google search, but I thought it an interesting and well written question nonetheless so I'm transcribing some of the results here to help anyone else:

From [this blog post](https://zellwk.com/blog/publishing-npm-packages-that-can-be-used-in-browsers-and-node/):

> UMD
>
> UMD (Universal Module Definition) is a block of code we can use to wrap around our library. This block of code makes it possible to use a library both on the frontend and in Node.
>
> It kinda looks like this:
>
> ```
>     (function (root, factory) {
>         if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
>             // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
>             define(['b'], factory);
>         } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
>             // Node.
>             module.exports = factory(require('b'));
>         } else {
>             // Browser globals (root is window)
>             root.returnExports = factory(root.b);
>         }
>     }(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this, function (b) {
>         // Use b in some fashion.
>
>         // Just return a value to define the module export.
>         // This example returns an object, but the module
>         // can return a function as the exported value.
>         return {};
>     }));
> ```

You can read more about [UMD here](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

Usually I would recommend you use a bundler / build tool to automate this for you and make the code available in even more environments.

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) is a a good choice for this.

Comment: Thanks! I tried searching, but I didn't really know what exactly to search for. I ended up searching stuff like how to publish to NPM as well as CDN, keeping code between NPM and CDN in sync and the results didn't help. So this is what I was looking for. Much appreciated for taking time to reply!